# Script to find the newest of a list of files

Tags: shell-script, shell

I need to write a script called `newer.sh` which given a list of files,
returns the newest one. That is, typing:

```
newer.sh /some/file other-file /and/so/on
```

will return the name of the newest file in the list.

This is what I have been able to come up with till now:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Newest file:"
ls -t | head -n 1
```

It does actually return the latest file created on the basis of its time of creation, but only among the files in the current directory.

Comment: show your efforts. Also, *Given a list of filenames* - is it a static list or they are all in the same folder?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows zero effort and is obviously homework

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am new to shell, bash and linux and have no idea how to go about it. I have actually been able to get some result, but from a very basic command: echo "Newer List"
ls -t | head -n1. It does return the latest file, after testing it 3 times. But, I am not sure if my command is correct.

Comment: @jasonwryan well, I will not stop you sir. But for someone who has no idea about this stuff, I thought people here would be kinder than this.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas all I have done is copied the question. You can imagine how difficult it is for me to interpret it, and write a code on it as well.

Comment: @ShivangChaturvedi putting a question on hold is temporary. You just need to edit it and improve it to fix the issues raised. Since you've now added something that shows you've at least tried and aren't just expecting us to do your homework for you, it has been reopened.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, edits and answers. I tried my best to come up with probably the most basic answer. This is a part of an assignment. Just a part of it, really. I am working on the rest of it, and have posted another question, with a lot more working. I'll be happy to receive some help from you all. And yes, I am a beginner. I have just taken up the course :)

Comment: @ShivangChaturvedi Welcome to U&L and the world of Linux then :) Here are some tips about asking questions that you might find useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/asking Have a great journey :)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU tools:

```
#! /bin/bash -
export LC_ALL=C
eval "files=($(ls -dt --quoting-style=shell-always -- "${@?}"))"
((${#files[@]} > 0)) && printf '%s\n' "${files[0]}"
```

For symlinks, that would consider the last-modification time of the symlink itself. If you'd rather it be that of the target of the symlink, add the `-L` option to `ls`.

If you want to add the restriction that no file paths given as argument may contain newline characters, you can write:

```
#! /bin/sh -
# only works for file paths that don't contain newline characters
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && ls -td -- "$@" | head -n 1
```

and remove the dependency  on GNU tools.

The principle is the same: use `ls -t`'s ability to sort files by modification time and get the first in that list. But here, `ls` outputs the list of files one on each line which makes it impossible to parse reliably unless you can guarantee that none of the file paths will contain newline characters (otherwise, you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between a file called `a<newline>b` and two `a` and `b` files and if `a<newline>b` was the newest file, `head -n 1` would only display the `a` giving in effect the wrong result).

Compared to your approach, here, we're passing the list of arguments that the script received (`"$@"`) to `ls` (after a `--` so that those arguments are treated by `ls` as file operands and not options) and passing the `-d` option so that `ls` doesn't list the *content* of those files that are of type *directory*. We're also not doing it if the script received 0 arguments (`$#` == 0) as otherwise, `ls -td --` would list the current directory, so you'd get `.` as output.

Instead of GNU `ls`, you could also use GNU `stat` to retrieve the file's modification time in a way that can be sorted with GNU `sort`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
export TZ=UTC0 LC_ALL=C
stat --printf '%y@%n\0' -- "$@" | sort -rz | sed -z 's/^[^@]*@//;q' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

(with a recent version of GNU `sed` for `-z`). Or using GNU `awk`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
export TZ=UTC0 LC_ALL=C
stat --printf '%y@%n\0' -- "$@" | awk -v RS='\0' '
  NR == 1 || $0 > newest {newest = $0}
  END {if (NR) {sub(/[^@]*@/, "", newest); print newest}}'
```

Comment: While I don't believe that this is what a beginner needs to do his homework, I suggest to add `-q` to the `ls` options in the second script to make it work with newlines.

Comment: @Philippos, depends what we mean by _work_. Returning `a?b` for a file called `a\nb` or `a\tb` instead of `a` (or `a<tab>b`) may be more useful when the result is intended for display-only to a user, but it would do more harm than help if it's meant to be post-processed, like `ls -ld -- "$(newest.sh *.txt)"`

Comment: In this case use the `-b` option instead (GNU `ls`). You can use `echo -e` to revert the escaping for further processing: `/bin/echo -e $(ls -tdb -- "$@" | head -n 1)`

Comment: @Philippos, no, that doesn't work. For instance, `ls -b 'a b'` outputs `a\ b` and even assuming `/bin/echo` is GNU `echo` and POSIXLY_CORRECT is not in the environment, `echo -e 'a\ b'` outputs `a\ b`, not `a b` (not to mention the problems with blanks and wildcards because of the missing quotes, or problems with files called `-e` or `-n`, `-nen`...). Also `ls -b $'\x80'` outputs `\200` when `echo` expects `\0200`.